# Using requests to access third-party API needing Oauth2 google authentication

Tags: python, python-requests

For test automation purpose, I would like to use requests and requests-oauthlib library to access an API.

The API use an oauth2 authentication with google account, however it's not a google API. As my test tool should be able to run unattended, I would like to be able to obtain an access token that I could then refresh automatically for an indefinite amount of time.

Something looking like this example from requests-auth documentation would be great. It involves a manual login once, and then I can refresh the token.
https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/google.html

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_id="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret="xxxxx"

redirect_uri = 'https://localhost/callback'
authorization_base_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
token_url ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

scope = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    ]


google = OAuth2Session(client_id, scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

# Redirect user to Google for authorization
authorization_url, state = google.authorization_url(authorization_base_url,
    access_type="offline", prompt="select_account")

print 'Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url    

redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
google.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, 
    authorization_response=redirect_response)

r = google.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo')
print r.content
```

However, I need to adapt to my API, and I can't find a way.

I can set authorization_base_url = "https://example.net/.auth/login/google"
and obtain the redirection URL but it doesn't work afterward. 
I don't know either what I should set as scope.

Should I get Id and secret from the API provider ?
Or is there other solution ?